# OpenMesh Plane3d

Tags: python, openmesh

I'm new to OpenMesh and have a very basic question. I’m trying to create a plane with OpenMesh in python. I have tried the following and it doesn’t work:

```
import openmesh as om
om.Plane3d(om.vec3f(0,0,1),point)
```

So first of all I get an error message saying that

> om has no module called Plane3d

I also tried with `om.VDPM.Plane3d` and `om.Geometry.Plane3d`, same results.
How do I call the function that creates a plane?

Secondly, as I read the documentation (http://www.openmesh.org/Daily-Builds/Doc/a01919.html) Plane3d takes in a vector and a point.
How do I create a point?
Is a point the same in OpenMesh as a vector?

Comment: How are you writing this? If it is in an IDE you would need to get the relevant path of the `openmesh python module`.

Comment: Yes, I'm writing this in PyCharm. OpenMesh is installed in an Anaconda environment, which I use as the PyCharm interpreter. So shouldn't PyCharm already have the path?

Comment: I had a similar issue with `ParaView` running `ParaView pvpython`. And i got it sorted by adding the path to`PyCharm`.

Comment: Add to the paths, `Settings` => `Project Interpreter` => Click the wheel next to the interpreter you use => `More` => `Show paths for the selected interpreters` => then Add the path

Comment: Are you sure that there are Python bindings for ``Plane3d``?